# Equivalent of a heap profiler but for the stack?

Tags: rust, stack-overflow, valgrind, sanitizer

I'm hitting a stack overflow where a (Rust default) stack size of 2 MiB is insufficient and a very basic piece of code crashes. If I set `RUST_MIN_STACK=4159616`, then it works as expected. `RUST_MIN_STACK=4159615` fails with a stack overflow.

The call chain is not very deep which makes me think something is allocating a lot of space on the stack before the crashing code, but I'm not sure what (this is within my unit test startup code which is trying to set up the Glommio async runtime). I've printed the size of the variable that the code is copying on the stack and it's 350 KiB - surprisingly large (it's a Rust closure) but also shouldn't be an issue if there's no other major stack allocation.

Is there any tool / technique to help narrow down what's causing such large stack usage? I've tried valgrind/massif & asan but they haven't told me any extra information as they really only seem to be implemented for heap allocations.

To add to the mystery, while the LTO release build crashes, it needs less additional space  (`RUST_MIN_STACK=2774720`). This implies that whatever I'm doing is causing the debug build to spill ~1.38 MiB onto the stack.

Update:

I'm still not sure where the stack allocations are coming from, but it looks like the problematic pattern is:

```
fn run_async<T>(future: impl std::future::Future<Output = T>) -> T {
  let ex = glommio::LocalExecutorBuilder::new(...).make().unwrap();
  ex.run(future)
}

#[test]
fn mytest() {
  // There's nothing before run_async.
  run_async(async move {
     // test code
  });
}
```

Even though I printed the size of the closure in `run_async` and it was only 350 KiB directly, there seems to be hidden stack usage being generated. I think maybe by the async machinery because while:

```
#[test]
fn mytest() {
  // There's nothing before run_async.
  run_async(async move {
     eprintln!(
         "closure enter with stack remaining {:?}",
         stacker::remaining_stack()
             .map(|s| MemorySize::new(s))
             .unwrap_or_else(|| MemorySize::new(1))
     );
     let _file = File::open_or_create("/dev/null").await.unwrap();
  });
}
```

uses almost no stack (1916112 bytes remaining from 2 MiB limit),

```
#[test]
fn mytest() {
  // There's nothing before run_async.
  run_async(async move {
     eprintln!(
         "closure enter with stack remaining {:?}",
         stacker::remaining_stack()
             .map(|s| MemorySize::new(s))
             .unwrap_or_else(|| MemorySize::new(1))
     );
     let file = File::open_or_create("/dev/null").await.unwrap();
     file.write(...).await.unwrap();
  });
}
```

uses nearly 1 MiB of stack according to stacker (1196432 bytes remaining).

As I add more async operations within the async method under test, the stack size implied by the future grows for some reason until it's too large to fit on the stack.

I've fixed it by allocating the future via `run_async(Box::pin(async move { ... code ... }))` but I'm still not clear about how to discover ahead of time when I have huge futures / when they're causing a lot of spillage onto the stack for some reason.

Comment: Futures can grow _very_ large very easily. Print the size (`std::mem::size_of_val()`) of each top level future. If it is indeed the problem, you can box it. This is unlikely to help in debug builds, but in release builds it will likely build them on the heap.

Comment: As I mention, that reports only 350kib directly, but boxing the future moved more than 2 Megs off the stack. There’s some kind of extra bookkeeping that’s getting triggered that’s not accounted for by size_of_val.

Comment: Generally, since stack allocation is ~0 cost, profiling tools don't measure it and instead concentrate on the heap. Does massif `--stacks=yes` do what you want?